# R programming (function and time series index)

Tags: r, function, for-loop, time-series

I'm programming with using R.

and I have to make function and for loop.

Value : t=0.001, n=4 and functions attached below.

[image: Click the function image file link]

I want to calculate y<sub>2</sub>(0.001), y<sub>3</sub>(0.001) and y<sub>4</sub>(0.001) by using for loop.

Also, I made a R code, but there is a error that I don't know.

How can I made for loop to calculate y<sub>2</sub>(0.001), y<sub>3</sub>(0.001) and y<sub>4</sub>(0.001)?

And below code is my R code. Thank You.

```
###########################
#   value                 #
###########################    
n<-4
t<-0.001
sigma<-numeric(4)
y<-numeric(4)
sigma[1]<-0.1
y[1]<-0

###########################
#   Brownian-Motion       #
###########################
nor1<-rnorm(n,0,1)
nor1<-cumsum(nor1)

###########################
#   function              #
###########################
delta<-function(t){
  0.01
}
alpha<-function(t){
  2*t*(1-t)
}
beta<-function(t){
  2*t*(1-t)
}
epsilon<-function(t){
  (2^(200*t))*(nor1)*(1/sqrt(log10(2)))
}

###########################
#   for-loop              #
###########################
sigma[i]<-delta(t)+(alpha(t)*y[i-1]*y[i-1])+(beta(t)*sigma[i-1]sigma[i-1]);
y[i]<-sigma[i]*epsilon(t);
print(y[i])
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! what are they supposed to do? You need to specify the question little more, for us it is impossible to understand the error message as well. Do you have some functions and do you want to run all of them?

Comment: @JanSila Oh, sorry! I attach my function to link and my R code!

Comment: There is no `for` keyword in your code. You may need to add `for (i in 2:n){` at the beginning of 'for' loop. Also `*` is missing in `sigma[i]` formula. Hope this should fix your error.

Comment: good point @Prem but the problem is also, that epsion returns a vector of length `n` and OP wants to save scalars into a vector. @Hyun can you figure that one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things I would polish (comment if you want more details), but your besides point made by @Prem, you had wrongly specified the for loop as such (maybe run through a tutorial on loops in R) and the sigma multiplication.

But mostly, the epsilon function returned a vector  - a value for each observations - instead of a single value. So I fixed it to be dependent on `i` as is in 2).

```
epsilon<-function(t,i){
  (2^(200*t))*(nor1[i])*(1/sqrt(log10(2)))
}
```

Then the for loop works as such:

```
for (i in 2:n){
sigma[i]<-delta(t)+(alpha(t)*y[i-1]*y[i-1])+(beta(t)*sigma[i-1]*sigma[i-1]);
y[i]<-sigma[i]*epsilon(t,i);
print(y[i])
}
```

Comment: Very thank you! The hard part is solved :)